# Data Profiling using TSQL and Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I would like to know the T-SQL used for data profiling, I believe there are 5 types of data profile used, I am aware SSIS has its own data profiling control flow task, however I would want it as a stored procedure in SQL Server for convenience and something that is set-based, if possible. Can anyone provide the SQL or reference to a place that covers all 5 types? Ideally I need to run this against a catalogue from information.schema against all tables.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This rather long, but clever script](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Profiling/96398/) by Adam Aspin, I have used to profile a table of data. Don't want to paste script into here.